# can you have a taghandler class for a composite component (xhtml-based)

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

As soon as I define a composite component in a .taglib.xml to have a `<handler-class>`, the .xhtml file is ignored.

What I need is a xhtml/facelet based component with a component-type (UIComponent-derived class) and(!) also with a taghandler class. My aim is to catch all working on its child tags in order to be able to activate a custom cdi scope during this.

I found a way by looking at the richfaces impl.jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
    <factory>
        <tag-handler-delegate-factory>de.sundn.regionscoped.jsf.BehaviorsTagHandlerDelegateFactoryImpl</tag-handler-delegate-factory>
</factory>
</faces-config>
```

Implement the factory

```
package de.sundn.regionscoped.jsf;
import javax.faces.FacesWrapper;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.BehaviorHandler;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentHandler;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.ConverterHandler;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandlerDelegate;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandlerDelegateFactory;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.ValidatorHandler;

/**
 * @author Nick Belaevski
 */
public class BehaviorsTagHandlerDelegateFactoryImpl extends TagHandlerDelegateFactory implements
        FacesWrapper<TagHandlerDelegateFactory> {
    private TagHandlerDelegateFactory factory;

    public BehaviorsTagHandlerDelegateFactoryImpl(TagHandlerDelegateFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public TagHandlerDelegate createBehaviorHandlerDelegate(BehaviorHandler owner) {
        return factory.createBehaviorHandlerDelegate(owner);
    }

    @Override
    public TagHandlerDelegate createComponentHandlerDelegate(ComponentHandler owner) {

        // TagHandlers structure is created when view is compiled
        // so there's no need to check for BehaviorsStack

        if (owner instanceof BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper) {
            // this is to avoid StackOverflowError because of ComponentHandler constructor call
            return null;
        }

        ComponentHandler wrappedHandler = new BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper(owner);

        return factory.createComponentHandlerDelegate(wrappedHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public TagHandlerDelegate createConverterHandlerDelegate(ConverterHandler owner) {
        return factory.createConverterHandlerDelegate(owner);
    }

    @Override
    public TagHandlerDelegate createValidatorHandlerDelegate(ValidatorHandler owner) {
        return factory.createValidatorHandlerDelegate(owner);
    }

    @Override
    public TagHandlerDelegateFactory getWrapped() {
        return factory;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Answer is: no you can't so I suppose. But there is something better. jsf allows to define `<tag-handler-delegate-factory>` in the `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: Theoretically you don't need to go that way. In tomahawk there is a component called t:aliasBean and t:aliasBeanScope that does something similar to what you want. Take a look at the code, it could be helpful for you.